# PPTX to PDF -> Hyperlinks failed

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint 2007 document with hyperlinks to other slides and external docs both on the master layout and on serveral slides. When I try to convert it to PDF, it loses all the hyperlinks.

I have the following Questions:

Which PDF-Converter does not kill my Hyperlinks made in the Powerpoint Layout master? 
I tried Adobe and DoPDF. And how do I have to setup the prog/converter?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PowerPoint 2007, you can install the [Microsoft Save as PDF](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1fc413c-6d89-4f15-991b-63b07ba5f2e5&displaylang=en) Add-in. Then when you save the presentation from within Powerpoint 2007, move your mouse over the little arrow next to Save As... and select PDF.

[image]